# Pause the program to check variable values in C#

Tags: c#

I am running a C# console application which for example is the following:

```
int sum=0;
for (i=1;i<100000000;i++)
{
    sum+=getSomeAlmostRandomValue();
    // if (i%10000==0)
    // Console.WriteLine(sum/i);
}
```

In simple words, i want to check the average of the results for a big number of iterations.

At some times, i want to check the average so far, to see how it is going... But checking the IF condition every time in the iteration, is probably too dumb/time-consuming. (This is just an example to introduce my problem. I know that i can break the for loop into 2 nested for loops in order not to have the IF. But still, maybe i don't want to WriteLine every some iterations). So my real question is the following:

Is there a way (by deleting the 2 commented rows) **to pause the program at will** and check the value of my variables (i,sum)

Comment: It's called debugging, use breakpoint and debug mode

Comment: A combination of conditional breakpoints and the 'immediate' window will solve your problem.

Comment: Press the "Pause" menu button in Visual Studio. It should be next to the "Play" button that starts debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers,

You got me into checking debugging options and i found exactly what i needed.

What solved my problem was the "Break All" button. When i press it, the program pauses and i can mouseover on the variables and check their values.

But I use C# Express 2010 and the "Break All" was not on my toolbar. So this is how i enabled it:

```
Tools -> Customize -> Commands -> Toolbar -> Debug -> Add Command -> Debug -> Break All
```

Answer (score 5):

Conditional break point is your choice.

Right click on the break point, set the conditions there. 
See also [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/03/set-a-simple-breakpoint-condition-vstipdebug0021.aspx) here.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't this conditional breakpoint time-consuming(checking the condition in every iteration)? What i want is to check the values at will. For example now, and then after 1 minute and then after half an hour

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis If you want to check them at will, the pause button on the debugger toolbar in Visual Studio will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional breakpoints and debug the application. For example, your modulus logic can be used as the breakpoint condition:

```
i % 10000 == 0
```

Which will hit the breakpoint for every 10,000 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This looks ripe for a unit test that can assert the correct values, completely negating the need to periodically check manually, but I can't help you there because I don't know what this is trying to do.</sub>

In this particular example, I would use a conditional breakpoint in the IDE.

However, if you want to do it in code, you can break using the `System.Diagnostics.Debugger` class, `Break()` method.

There are also helpful methods found in the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` class, such as `Assert`, `Fail`, `WriteLineIf`, etc.

It would look something like this:

```
int sum=0;
for (i=1;i<100000000;i++)
{
    sum+=getSomeAlmostRandomValue();

    if (i%10000==0)
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

The problem with `Debugger.Break` is that it will compile into release code, whereas most (if not all) of the `Debug` class methods are conditional on the `DEBUG` compiler symbol. This problem can be side-stepped using your own conditional code:

```
#if DEBUG
    Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

However, I tend to err away from leaving this code in the code-base once the debugging session has finished. That said, sometimes you'll find that leaving a little debug infrastructure around some troublesome legacy code can come in handy in future.

Answer (score -1):

If this is an application where you aren't in an development-environment you should look into the producer-consumer pattern. With it you can pause your application while also securing that the data will be produced fully before displayed.